# Can I run ROS on my computer? I am just starting ROS and wanted to know if I can run it on my laptop

Tags: ros

I have a Windows 10 laptop, with Intel i3 processor(10th gen), and 12 gb ram, with Intel UHD graphics 620, it is not a gaming laptop, and does not have a dedicated graphics card. Can I practice ROS on this laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's more than enough.
Here is a link to installation tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows
On [this website](https://www.theconstructsim.com/) you can find ROS Development Studio it's a cloud virtual machine with pre-installed ROS and you can try what you have in mind without installing ROS locally.